# Logistic Population growth, How to find r

Tags: initial-value-problems

The information that I am given: p(12)=95,75 ;  P(14)=98 ; and the carrying capacity K = 100.  Question : What is r,  as defined  in:

deltaP/P = -r/K * P + r

The answer in the book is 0,325

The closest I have come is 0.388

Please let me know how to solve this problem. Thanks.

This is my working:

[My attempt at answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8W8MM.png)
[My answer[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4LpY.jpg)

Comment: are you sure its dP/P or dP/dt * 1/P

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the best thing to do would be to solve the differential equation and then plug in values of $t$ and $P$.

I believe you forgot a $dt$ in the denominator so I'll add that in.

$\displaystyle \frac{dP}{P\cdot dt} = -\displaystyle \frac{r}{K}(P)+r$

can be rewritten as $\displaystyle \frac{dP}{dt} = rP\left(1-\frac{P}{K}\right)$.

This is the more conventional forme that suggests that growth slows down as population (P) approaches carrying capacity (K).

Anyways, the next step is to solve the equation.

[image]

This is a clean solution, taken from https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~mlerma/courses/math214-2-04f/notes/c2-logist.pdf,  and in this example, $r$ is replaced with $k$. They represent the growth factor.

Now, all you have to do is plug in values of $t$ and $P$ and you can solve for $r$. Good luck!

Comment: This is exactly what I did. I used P(12) in the place of P(0) and P(14) in the place of P, and t=2 for 2 periods of time.   It gave me k = 0.388 but the book says I should get 0.325.

Comment: I am really pleased that I appear to be on the right track but can you suggest where I made my  mistake please

Comment: oh no!! that's where you went wrong

Comment: you should be using P(12) and t=12, and P(14) and t=14

Comment: P(12) is not the beginning, rather it is 12 periods of time after the start, so t=12 necessarily

Comment: I have put my revised attempt at an answer into the question post above and used p(12) and p(14) . I set up a simultaneous and this eliminates the need to know p(0). but am still getting 0.388 as an answer.  Your comment would be muchly appreciated.

Comment: How did they know "k = 0.031476" in the northwestern example?

Comment: This value is supplied within the problem. I don't think they already knew that. It is a parameter that is part of the differential equation @HarryIguana